# Approximate a product of Beta PDFs with another Beta PDF

Tags: beta-distribution, numerics

The PDF of the generalized Beta distribution in the interval $[A,B]$ is defined as:

$$f(x) = \frac{(x-A)^{\alpha-1}(B-x)^{\beta-1}}{(B-A)^{\alpha+\beta-1}\mathrm{B}(\alpha,\beta)}$$

for $A<x<B$, and $f(x)=0$ otherwise. Here we assume that $\alpha,\beta>1$ and $A<B$.

Consider a PDF which is the product of PDFs of generalized Beta distributions:

$$g(x) \propto \prod_{i}\left(x-A_{i}\right)^{\alpha_{i}-1}\left(B_{i}-x\right)^{\beta_{i}-1}$$

for $\max_i A_i < x < \min_i B_i$, and $g(x)=0$ otherwise. A normalization constant is implied. Here we assume that $\alpha_i,\beta_i>0$ for all $i$ and $\max A_i < \min B_i$.

How can I best approximate $g(x)$ by another generalized Beta distribution in the interval $[A,B]$, where $A=\max A_i$ and $B=\min B_i$?

More precisely, what is a reliable, accurate, and efficient method, to obtain a pair of values $\alpha,\beta$ that make $f(x)$ a good approximation to $g(x)$?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does this product operation model?

Comment: @whuber Nothing that I know of, really. I was just playing around and noticed (after doing some numerical simulations) that $g(x)$ can be well approximated by $f(x)$, given a suitable choice of $\alpha,\beta$. Now I just need a sound method to find $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: I suspect @whuber is being polite. The product of the pdfs you are calculating provides the joint pdf of $(X_1,X_2, \dots, X_n)$ ... i.e. the multivariate joint pdf of $(X_1,X_2, \dots, X_n)$ where $X_i \sim GenBeta(\alpha_i, \beta_i, A_i,B_i)$. By contrast, you appear to desire (i) a _univariate_ pdf you term $g(x)$; (ii) your 'truncation' of the domain of support to $(max_iA_i, min_iB_i)$ appears peculiar:  why have a model which depends on $A_i, B_i$ if you just throw out that detail? Why not set general $A$ and $B$ from the start? And what do you think the product of the pdfs represents?

Comment: @wolfies As you mention, $g(x)$ is proportional to the multivariate joint pdf of $(X_1, X_2 ,\ldots,X_n)$, evaluated at $x_1 = x_2 = \ldots = x_n$. If you want, you can interpret it as "the probability density that,  $X_1, X_2, \ldots, X_n$ all equal $x$, given that they are all equal". Since $X_i$ is confined to $[A_i,B_i]$ and $X_j$ to $[A_j,B_j]$, if $x_i = x_j$, their common value necessarily lies in $[\max(A_i,A_j), \min(B_i,B_j)]$.

Comment: But as I said before, I am not really interested in the interpretation of the product. I am only interested in the numerical approximation of it.